# How do I query a token and send push notifications inside cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently very stuck in `push notifications`.

I set up everything correctly and I know how to send push notifications through the cloud messaging console. But I just need to send personalized `push notifications` to specific devices.

I have never worked with **`node.js`** before and I am working for a whole week one this right now, without any results.

I save `deviceToken` in this way:

```
void notificationHandling() async {
    final fbm = FirebaseMessaging();
    fbm.requestNotificationPermissions();
    fbm.configure(
      onMessage: (message) {
        print(message);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (message) {
        print(message);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (message) {
        print(message);
        return;
      },
    );
    fbm.getToken();
    fbm.subscribeToTopic('deal');
    String fbmToken = await fbm.getToken();

    // Save it to Firestore
    if (fbmToken != null) {
      var tokens = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(uid)
          .collection('tokens')
          .doc(fbmToken);

      await tokens.set({
        'token': fbmToken,
        'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), // optional
        'platform': Platform.operatingSystem // optional
      });
    }
  }
```

I call this function in **`initState();`**

My **`index.js`** file is as followed:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("messages/{message}")
    .onWrite((event) => {
      const query = await database
          .collection("users")
          .doc(event.after.data().uid[0])
          .collection("tokens")
          .get();

      const tokens = query.docs.map((snap) => snap.id);

      return admin.messaging().send(tokens, {
        notification: {
          title: "Nieuw bericht",
          body: "Je hebt een nieuw bericht van Quick Fix Repair",
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        }});
    });
```

Does anyone now how I can fix this and **send** the **`push notifications`** to a specific device token? I am very stuck.

Thanks in advance!

**PS:** I call `event.after.data().uid[0]` because `uid` is an array containing **`UID`** strings, but I am not sure how to send the notification to everyone whose **`UID`** is inside the **`UID`** Array

Comment: What is the purpose of using token subcollection for a user?

Comment: In order for you to send a notification to a specific device, you have to obtain their token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("messages/{message}")
    .onWrite((event) => {
      const query = await database
          .collection("users")
          .doc(event.after.data().uid[0])
          .collection("tokens")
          .get();

      const tokens = query.docs.map((snap) => snap.id);

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,
      {
        notification: {
          title: "Nieuw bericht",
          body: "Je hebt een nieuw bericht van Quick Fix Repar",
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        }
      },
      {
        "priority": "high",
        "contentAvailable": true
        });
    });
```